# Is it possible to remove batch dimension from frozen graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Checking frozen tensorflow model:

```
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_v3_2016_08_28_frozen.pb.tar.gz
```

I see that input size is `Tensor 'input:0', which has shape '(1, 299, 299, 3)'`, I wonder is it possible to make input `(None, 299, 299, 3)` to make availible batch prediction with batch_size > 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case it may not be possible to do this, as there could be operations that rely on the first dimension being 1 (e.g. suppose [`tf.squeeze`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze) is used on `input:0`). However, you can try to replace the input with a placeholder of the desired shape. You can do this with [`tf.graph_util.import_graph_def`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/graph_util/import_graph_def). If the operations allow it, then TensorFlow should import the graph adjusting the node shapes accordingly. See the following example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# First graph
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 10, 20], name='Input')
    y = tf.square(x, name='Output')
    print(y)
    # Tensor("Output:0", shape=(1, 10, 20), dtype=float32)
    gd = tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()

# Second graph
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10, 20], name='Input')
    y, = tf.graph_util.import_graph_def(gd, input_map={'Input:0': x},
                                        return_elements=['Output:0'], name='')
    print(y)
    # Tensor("Output:0", shape=(?, 10, 20), dtype=float32)
```

In the first graph, the `Output:0` node has a shape `(1, 10, 20)`, which is inferred from the shape of the `Input:0` tensor. However, when I take the graph definition from the first graph and load in the second graph, replacing the `Input:0` tensor with a placeholder with undefined first dimension, the shape of `Output:0` is updated to `(?, 10, 20)`. If I run the operations in the second graph giving an input value with a first dimension greater than one, it will work as expected, because the graph is correct.